# JWT stateless sign-on with secure cookie storage : how to implement log out?

Tags: javascript, security, single-sign-on, single-page-application, jwt

I am starting to implement a JWT based Single Sign On system (for several single page apps under the same domain, so something like `app1.mydomain.com`, `app2.mydomain.com`, `auth.mydomain.com`) using the mechanisms described in [this article from Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa).

In order to protect my signed JWT token from XSS attacks, I want to store the token in a secure (HTTPS only) and HTTP-only cookie. The SPA itself will get the user info from the response body.

My main question is how can we implement a "log out" feature in JavaScript, since the cookie is, by design, not accessible from the JS code?

I am guessing that I will have to make a server call that will expire the cookie. Is there a pure-client-side way to do it though?

Comment: Handle the logout on server side by overiding the expiration ?

Comment: @JEY : yes that is what I tought, I was just hoping maybe there is a client-side only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to do the cleanup server-side as user JEY already suggested.

<sub>Additionally, I wanted to extend the bit on the possibilities so this did not fit a comment.</sub>

When dealing with browser-based applications selecting the token storage is almost a pick your poison game. If you go with a secure HTTP-only cookie you don't have to worry about XSS vulnerabilities leading to token disclosure. However, you'll still have to ensure you're not vulnerable to XSS by an whole set of another reasons.

This means you don't save any actual work, you just get that fuzzy feeling that if you do get compromised by XSS at least the token is safe.

On the other hand, by going with a cookie, CSRF is now something that needs to be on your radar and here is where things may get funny, some trivial methods of preventing CSRF like double-submit cookies can be [implemented in such ways that they are virtually useless in the presence of exploitable XSS vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59470/double-submit-cookies-vulnerabilities) in child domains for example.

**I'm not saying that storing tokens in cookies is plain wrong, it isn't, likewise storing them in Web storage is also acceptable.** In both cases you need to understand the consequences of your choice and the possibilities each one brings.

In this case, Web storage would simplify your logout scenario from a client-side perspective so you need to ask yourself which set of pros and cons are better suited for your scenario.

Given you mentioned multiple applications in child domains one thing to be aware of is the following:

> With token-based auth, you are given the choice of where to store the JWT. Commonly, the JWT is placed in the browsers local storage and this works well for most use cases. **There are some issues with storing JWTs in local storage to be aware of. Unlike cookies, local storage is sandboxed to a specific domain and its data cannot be accessed by any other domain including sub-domains.**

(emphasis is mine, source: *Where to Store Tokens?* section of [Cookies vs Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/))

(**Disclosure:** I'm an Auth0 engineer.)

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer. So would you say that if I want to have some kind of SSO-like feature, using the same token for different subdomains, a cookie with a `.mydomain.com` domain is the only option (for browser-based app) ?

Comment: I would say it would be the simplest to implement for that scenario, given the exact same domain requirement that Web storage imposes. However, it's possible to achieve SSO even on applications of completely unrelated domains so this scenario would also be supported. You can check [SSO](https://auth0.com/docs/sso) for an example of this.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stick with cookies for JWT storage. By the way, the link in your comment id badly formatted.